# How to check if a specific index in a list is x?

Tags: python, tic-tac-toe

I am trying to check if the user's input in a list is the same as "X" or "O" in my tic-tac-toe game, but I get the error

```py
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'
```

for this code:

```py
  player1 = input("Where do you want to place your X, player 1? (row number, space, number)")
  if(moves[int(player1[0] - 1)][int(player1[2] - 1)] == "X" or moves[int(player1[0] - 1)][int(player1[2] - 1)] == "O" ):
    print("Spot taken try again")
    playerInput()
```

I realize this might not be the best way of doing this so if you have a improvement please suggest it!

Comment: Typo: should be `int(player1[0]) - 1`

Comment: @Austin doing this now gives the error `TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable`

Answer (score 0):

You should be converting the input to `int` *and then* subtracting 1, but you're trying to subtract 1 before converting to `int`. Also, there's no need to access the value twice. You could do this:

```
spot = moves[int(player1[0]) - 1][int(player1[2]) - 2]

if spot == 'O' or spot == 'X':
    print('Spot taken, try again.')
```